# Change color when onPressed in flutter using Provider

Tags: flutter, provider, flutter-provider

How can I change the color using Provider State Management instead of `setState()`

I have one Button by default color is black then - 1st click color is blue, 2nd click color is red, 3rd click color is green 4th click color is black(by default) or purple how can I do it using Provider

Model:

```
class DriverStatusState extends ChangeNotifier {
  var numberOfClicks = 0;
  Color buttonColor = Colors.red;

  void changeColor() {
    numberOfClicks++;
    mapNumerOfClicksToColor(numberOfClicks);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  mapNumerOfClicksToColor(int num) {
    switch (num) {
      case 1:
        {
          buttonColor = Colors.orange;
        }
        break;
      case 2:
        {
          buttonColor = Colors.green;
        }
        break;
      default:
        {
          buttonColor = Colors.red;
        }
        break;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Widget:

```
Consumer<DriverStatusState>(
            builder: (context, state, _) => ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('press me'),
              onPressed: () {
                state.mapNumerOfClicksToColor(0);
                     },
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: state.buttonColor),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: you can create a setter for color value, then  call `notifyListener();`

Comment: @pmatatias how can I do that? can you provide me proper answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hold the number of clicks inside a variable, and every time you click the button, you will increment the varibale, and change the color according to the new value.

Assuming you are familiar with Provider, you would do something like this inside your model:

```
var numberOfClicks = 0;
Color buttonColor = Colors.white;


void changeColor(){
   numberOfClicks++;
   mapNumerOfClicksToColor(numberOfClicks);
   notifyListeners();
}

mapNumerOfClicksToColor(int num){
  switch(num){
    case 1:
       buttonColor = Colors.Blue;
    case 2:
        ....
    case 3:
        ....
  }
 notifyListeners();
}
```

Comment: Hussein Qabalan not working I have update my question

Comment: You need to call changeColor not the other function. Call it like this Provider.of<DriverStatusState>(context).changeColor ()

Comment: On onPressed fun?

Comment: Yeah. And that function will handle the color change logic depending on the new value

Comment: state.changeColor(); also not work

Comment: can you do that?

Comment: Provider.of<DriverStatusState>(context).changeColor ()

Comment: not working above comment solution

Comment: Could you please share your ChangeNotifierProvider?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246948/discussion-between-ravindra-s-patil-and-hussein-qabalan).

Comment: Can I repeat this statement like infinite loop
Like when Last no is red and it will be starting again index 1

Comment: when you hit default in switch case, reassign numberOfClicks to 0.